# CreateView template with ManyToMany fields

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

I'm dabbling with Django and I'm facing a problem I cannot solve. I have a M2M relationship between three tables and I want to create a CreateView. For the sake of simplifying, let's say we have this three models:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=20, unique=True)

class Recipe(models.Model):
    recipe_name = models.Charfield(max_length=20, unique=True)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, through=Units)

class Unit(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, ....
    ingredient_units = models.FloatField()
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, ....)
```

When creating the new recipe (in a CreateView template), the user should introduce the recipe name, then has to select one of the current ingredients (in a select HTML tag) and add the units of that ingredient (2). Also, I want to add a button that adds a new row with an Ingredient select and a Unit field to add as many rows the user wants, and save it.

The problem is, I don't know how to add fields from a M2M relationship to a CreateView template, nor how to save the Recipe at the same time as the many Units tuples.

This is already working on the Admin section:

[Admin example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTFNu.png)

but I want the same for the users on the front end.

The question then is: How I can add fields from other model and save them when the form saves?

Comment: You need a [model formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets), specifically an inline formset.

Comment: I used `inlineformset_factory` in the `forms.py` for this issue + `jquery.formset` library for the frontend.

Comment: Finally I removed the ManyToManyField, then proceed as Daniel Roseman and King Reload said and created the forms at forms.py, then the Formset with both forms tied together and it worked. 

Thanks a lot for your (quick) replies!

Comment: No problem David :)